# Peskin and Schroeder's QFT eq.(9.56)

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, gauge

On Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book, page 296, the book give the functional integral formula after inserting Faddeev and Popov's trick of identity.
$$ \int \mathcal{D} A e^{i S[A]}=\operatorname{det}\left(\frac{1}{e} \partial^2\right)\left(\int \mathcal{D} \alpha\right) \int \mathcal{D} A e^{i S[A]} \delta\left(\partial^\mu A_\mu-\omega(x)\right) .$$
where $\omega(x)$ is defined on (9.55) as a gauge-fixing function:
$$G(A)=\partial^\mu A_\mu(x)-\omega(x).\tag{9.55} $$
I am troubled for following statement:

> "This equality (my first equation) holds for any $\omega(x)$, so it will also hold if we replace the right-hand side (of my first equation) with any properly normalized linear combination involving different functions $\omega(x)$."
> $$N(\xi) \int \mathcal{D} \omega \exp \left[-i \int d^4 x \frac{\omega^2}{2 \xi}\right] \operatorname{det}\left(\frac{1}{e} \partial^2\right)\left(\int \mathcal{D} \alpha\right) \int \mathcal{D} A e^{i S[A]} \delta\left(\partial^\mu A_\mu-\omega(x)\right)\tag{9.56} $$
> where $N(\xi)$ is an unimportant normalization constant.

So how to understand this linear combination?

Comment: In the first equation, the functional integral has the same value for each such $\omega$, so averaging that over $\omega$ still gives that value. If $f$ is a PDF, $\int cfdx=c$.

Comment: Thank you very much. In your last formula, does $c$ be the expectation value? Thanks.

Comment: It's a constant, so is equal to its own expectation, yes.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you very much! Can I ask you a related quick question? In peskin's book page 295, they give Lorentz gauge $G\left(A^\alpha\right)=\partial^\mu A_\mu+(1 / e) \partial^2 \alpha$.  And they said (9.55) in my post is a generalization of Lorentz gauge. I am puzzled for their statement below (9.55), "The functional determinant is the same as in Lorentz gauge, det$\left(\delta G\left(A^\alpha\right) / \delta \alpha\right)=\operatorname{det}\left(\partial^2 / e\right)$" Why (9.55) this general case's determinant equal to Lorentz case? Thank you take time to help, I am really appreciate it.

Comment: @J.G. By the way, why can we regard $\omega(x)$ as constant in this $\int \mathcal{D}\omega$ integral?

Comment: What's constant is not $\omega$, but the first expression for $\int\mathcal{D}Ae^{iS[A]}$ in which it appears. As for why the determinant is the same, note $\delta G/\delta\alpha=\partial^2/e$.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you very much! Yes, I know that for Lorentz gauge: $\delta G/\delta\alpha=\partial^2/e
$, maybe I am confused about (9.55)'s definition. Previously, I thought their don't have $\alpha$ in (9.55), I don't know if we need to calculate $\delta G/\delta\alpha$, where $G$ is defined by (9.55). So I may lost the book's logic here, could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @J.G. In other words, this determinant is independent of gauge choice?

Comment: @J.G. I understand that by checking Srednicki's book, thank you very much!